# Uber SOA architecture processing

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture, soa, uber-api

I am designing a mobile application like UBER and looking at their architecture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhrYb.jpg
I know that the application resides in the google store ,but on the back-end side ,where do all the other components reside like the NOSQL database
represented as Node REgion 1,Node Region 2 ,...,Node Region 4 ,the "DISCO" and also where does the KAFKA processing happen?
Also, if someone can give a better explanation by explaining where the components shown on the picture reside and how they work one with another it will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can find useful information related to these topics at the Uber Engineering (https://eng.uber.com) site; and more specifically I think you could be interested in these articles , where they talk about their Kafka implementations (https://eng.uber.com/reliable-reprocessing/), some generals about their architecture (https://eng.uber.com/schemaless-part-one/) and about their data model; so you can find good answers and a guideline for your developments.